# android passing a json object from into a listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm new programming so I request a little help from anybody who is familiar with JSONArray and ArrayAdapters and listviews.  I just need somebody to give an example of passing a JSONObject from an activity into a listview in my situation.

```
 public class WhatsYourQuestion extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    EditText et; 

    TextView answer; 





    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(InstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {


            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
            new asynctask().execute();
            }
     }

       public class asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

           protected void onPreExcute(String q) {
             q = et.getText();
             }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
              static InputStream is = null;
              static JSONObject jObj = null;
              static String json = "";
              try{
                 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 URI website = new URI("http://example" + q.setText +"json");
                 HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                 request.setURI(website);
                 HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                 HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                 is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }


        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

               }

        }


        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURI(uwebsite);

        try[
           ResultsSet = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTSSET);

           for(int i = 0; i < ResultsSet.length(); i++){
           JSONObject r = ResultsSet.getJSONObject(i);


           String Subject = r.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
           String NumAnswers = r.getString(TAG_NUMANSWERS);


              }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        protected void OnPostExecute(String results){
        ??????
```

Now this is where I need to somebody to give me an example of how to pass my JSONObject from this activity into a listview.

Comment: I don't see a `ListView` in your activity. Neither do I see an `ArrayAdapter`. What will your `ListView` be populated with? Have you defined one in `main.xml`? And, off-topic, but quite importantly, shouldn't `super.onCreate(InstanceState);` be `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: I have created a listview in main.xml and do I put the ArrayAdapter and Listview under onPostExecute? sorry, this is new stuff to me.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what each list item will hold?

Comment: each list item will hold three things.  each will have a question, the subject of that question, and last it will display how many answers this question has.  I am using Yahoo Answers api here is a link if you want to check it out http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/questionSearch.html

Comment: Oh ok. This is fairly straightforward. And I see that you have already accepted an answer. Seems like your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might need an ArrayAdapter or class that extents from BaseAdapter, then pass your data(like JSONObject or something else) by adpater's constructor. so you can bind it to your listview.

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial is really useful for your problem. but might some edit in few code. androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/